# Can a maven dependency read a property-file in the main project?

Tags: java, maven, properties, dependency-management

I have two maven projects let's call them A and B. B is a dependency in A. Project B is an annotation processor which, among other things, contains a property reader looking like this

```
public class PropertyReader {
    private final Properties properties;

    public PropertyReader() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("projectB.properties");
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.load(is);
    }

    public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        return this.properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

In project A I have `projectB.properties` stored under `src/main/resources`. When I try to build project A, I get the following error when creating the above InputStream:

`Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null`

How can my project B read a properties file which is located in project A?

Comment: have you tried `getResourceAsStream("projectB.properties");` to use `getResourceAsStream("/projectB.properties");` instead?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. I'm thinking that my PropertyReader is looking for a property file in project B and not in A.

Comment: Technically `getResourceAsStream("...` looks into the classpath nothing related to projects etc...